# Difference between "comprender" and "entender"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

What's the difference if both mean "to understand"? One source (spanish.about.com) says the **comprender** implies a deeper understanding than **entender** but that doesn't help much. Is there any thumb-rule around their usage? Any regionalism?

Comment: se nota que no entendió bien :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entender and comprender are generally synonymous, but of course have uses particular to each one (as mentioned, *entender* can be an alternate for *to know*, slang for *to be gay*, or legally meaning *to affects* or *to pertain to*).  If a contrast must be made, however, it is that *entender* is a bit more superficial understanding as compared with *comprender*.  It's better to see with some examples:

- Para multiplicar dos números, tienes que ... ¿me entiendes?
  —Sí, te entiendo. <sub>(I understand the words that you are saying, that is, I can convert them to English in my head)</sub>
- Para multiplicar dos números, tienes que ... ¿comprendes?
  —Sí, comprendo. <sub>(I understand the concept of multiplying, it all makes sense now, thanks for explaining it!)</sub>
- Mi novia me ha dejado... ¿me entiendes?
  —Sí, te entiendo. <sub>(It means you're single, you've been played, you can't afford the apartment now, etc)</sub>
- Mi novia me ha dejado... ¿me comprendes?
  —Sí, te comprendo. <sub>(I've been there man, I know what you're going through)</sub>

Part of the reason for this is evident if you look at the other meanings for comprender (from the *DRAE*):

> **comprender**
>   1. *tr.* Abrazar, ceñir, rodear por todas partes algo.
>   2. *tr.* Contener, incluir en sí algo. *U. t. c. prnl.*
>   4. *tr.* Encontrar justificados o naturales los actos o sentimientos de otro.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that both words are **complete synonyms**, when they refer to `to understand`.

I don't think there is a proper rule of thumb, but I think I tend to use `comprender` when you understand something by your own means or studies, and `enteder` when you understand something because somebody explained something to you (meaning that there is some *transmission* of knowledge), but this may not apply to other Spanish speakers. `Entender` can also be used when there is some sort of understanding or communication between two entities.

> Los dos jefes de proyecto se conocieron ese día y se **entendieron** a la primera.

Meaning that it didn't take long for the two project leaders to understand each other (understand motivations and goals or get to common ground or agreement). I would naturally favor `entender` over `comprender` on this context.

Also, `entender`can also be used for the wisdom or knowledge you have gained (I would say that `entender` is a better synonym for `saber (to know about something)` than `comprender` is):

> Lleva muchos años trabajando en IBM y **entiende** mucho de ordenadores.

Comment: Yes diego , you are right. I recommend the use of entender, because it´s easier and don´t sound ugly in some cases such as : "el comprende mucho las computadoras" too much ugly to my ears. If you look in google you can see the difference :: "entiende mucho"
Aproximadamente 151.000 resultados "comprende mucho"
Aproximadamente 74.300 resultados

Answer (score 1):

In Chilean Spanish there is a difference of formality. In colloquial use always use "entender". In formal situations (dissertations, written texts, journalism ...) can be used both, but "comprender" is more marked.

Answer (score 0):

My translation follows:

- Comprender = to comprehend
- Entender = to understand